# Ways for browser to include page ID in query?

Tags: html, http

I'm no expert on web development, and need to find a way to let the browser call a PHP routine on the server with the current document ID as parameter, eg.

```
http://www.acme.com/index.php?id=1
```

I then need to call eg. /change.php with id=1 to do something about that document.

Unless I'm mistaken, there are three ways for the client to return this information:

- if passed as argument in the URL (as above), it will be available as HTTP referrer
- by including it as hidden field in
- by sending it as cookie

I suppose using a hidden field is the most obvious choice. Are there other ways? Which solution would you recommend? Any security issues to be aware?

Thank you.

Comment: Where/when/how do you have to call `change.php` ?

Comment: This was also asked at the new Web Dev site, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1432/ways-for-client-to-include-page-id-in-query just for reference.

Comment: Yes. I had to ask it here too since I was told that "This belongs on stackoverflow.com" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also POST the data so it won't be seen in the URL with ’form method = "post" ’

All of these methods are, to a point, insecure as they can be manipulated by a savvy user/hacker.  You could https your site, limiting any man in then middle attacks.  Be sure to check and validate incoming data

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is another option as well, and it allows you to send that information without refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can some AJAX embedded in the page be able to read the ID of the page it's in, and use this information to call a server-side script?

Comment: I guess the obvious solution to my problem is updating the server-side code so that hyperlinks/forms in the HTML page already include this information, so the browser doesn't have to figure it out.

Comment: You can either add a hidden div with the page ID, and have the Ajax read the ID from that div to call the server-side script, or have the Ajax read the ID from the URL of the page or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.acme.com/index.php?id=1
```

The above url would be more "browser friendly" if you transform it into something similar to this:

```
http://www.acme.com/index/page/1
```

I am sure you can achieve this in Apache. Or Java Servlets.

Comment: 'Browser-friendly' (by which you probably mean user-friendly / readable) is debatable with an anonymous id. It **is** however language-agnostic, also big step towards cool uri's (..don't change).